# "I'm going to invite..." VS "I'll invite"

Tags: future-time

The task is:

> Read these two sentences. Chose the one where Mike has already planned
>   to invite Daisy to St.-Petersburg.
>
> 1. I'm going to invite Daisy to St.-Petersburg.
> 2. I'll invite Daisy to St.-Petersburg.

I think the second one is correct as we are talking about immediate decision. `"To be going to"` is used for intention whereas he's just made up his mind. The key says about the first variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is not really enough *context* to say whether Mike has **already decided** to invite Daisy in one or the other of your sentences.

He might be saying to his friend

> I've bought the ticket already, and **I'm going to invite Daisy to St. Petersburg.**

To choose the second over the first, you may be making some cultural assumptions, or assumptions about Mike. The only unambiguous phrasing might be

> I'm inviting Daisy to St. Petersburg *(to see the bridges)*.

The only thing certain in all three scenarios is that Daisy may not know yet.

Comment: +1 I agree. With both answers Daisy may not yet know and the speaker may not have made a final decision yet. However, out of the two the second is closer to reality since **Going to** refers to the intentions.

Comment: if I say I am inviting Daisy that means that Mike as you say  has already bought the ticket , it is something that is sure now